# Object racking on conveyor belt using low cost Lidar or similar non-camera options

Tags: sensors, lidar, ultrasonic-sensors, laser

The requirement is that movement of products right from the start to end of the conveyor belt  (of length around 2.5 m) need to be tracked. The same can be easily done using any IP Camera and OpenCV but here we can not use Camera. I could think of Lidar as an alternative option but usually the cost is too high and vertical FOV is less. Any suggestion of applicable Lidars less costing than $500?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a shopping question

Comment: What about photoelectric sensors?